# Django: is using a ForeignKey likely to affect read performance on a big db?

Tags: django, postgresql

I have a largeish Postgres database (about 500m rows, 150GB in total). The data is relatively static (only updated once a quarter) so I want to optimise it for reading, not writing.

Currently I have the following database structure, using a ForeignKey:

```
 class Practice(models.Model):
    code = models.IntegerField()
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

 class Prescription(models.Model):
    practice = models.ForeignKey(Practice)
    presentation_code = models.CharField(max_length=15)
```

If I want to do queries like this frequently, returning large datasets:

```
 p = Practice.objects.filter(code=1234)
 prescriptions = Prescription.objects.filter(practice=p)
```

Would it be more efficient to reorganise the database so it doesn't have a ForeignKey:

```
 class Prescription(models.Model):
    practice_id = models.IntegerField()
    presentation_code = models.CharField(max_length=15)
```

and then do this in the view?

```
 p = Practice.objects.filter(code=1234)
 prescriptions = Prescription.objects.filter(practice_id=1234)
```

I understand that if I do this, I run the risk of creating orphaned rows in the data import - that's not a problem. I'm more interested in ensuring that the database runs quickly and can cope with multiple users.

Currently I have the first setup, and django-debug-toolbar shows that the view query looks like this:

```
 SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "frontend_prescription" WHERE 
   "frontend_prescription"."chemical_id" = '0212000AA';
```

Looking at that, perhaps we can infer that changing the database structure wouldn't speed up read queries?

I understand that I could test this by reorganising my database and checking the execution time, but with 500m rows that's quite a lot of work :)

Comment: No, that won't speed up performance. Internally, a foreign key is little more than an indexed `IntegerField` with a db constraint. The constraint won't affect single-table read performance, though it might (positively) affect read performance when using joins, i.e. `select_related`.

Comment: @knbk Thanks, that's what I was wondering. If you'd like to submit this as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that won't speed up performance. Internally, a foreign key is little more than an indexed `IntegerField` with a db constraint. The constraint won't affect single-table read performance, though it might (positively) affect read performance when using joins, i.e. `select_related`.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have indexes on your tables? In your case b-tree or hash would help.
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/indexes-types.html . Also please dont denormalize db, thats why you use sql database ...for normalization.

Comment: Yes, there are indexes on the foreign key columns.